# Catch Build Fail Ant

Tags: ant

I'm using a parrallel task to test and shutdown my server.

Here is the code :

```
        <target name="runandtest" description="run the server and test it">
          <parallel  timeout="1380000">
            <sshexec host="XXX.XX.XX.XX" username="XXXXX" password="xxxxxxxxx" trust="true" command='cd test;nohup bin/server > log.txt'/>
            <sequential>
              <sleep seconds="1200"/>
              <!-- run test-->
               <scp file="XXXXXX:XXXXXX@XXX.XX.XX.XX:/home/XXXXX/test/log.txt" todir="/ant/" trust="true" />           
               <mail enableStartTLS="true" mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" mailport="587" user="XXXXXXX" password="XXXXXXX" subject="Run test"  from="XXXXXXXX" tolist="XXXXXXX" files="log.txt" message="blabla"/>
            <!-- FAIL BELOW  -->       
               <sshexec host="XXX.XX.XX.XX" username="XXXX" password="XXXXX" trust="true" command="kill $(ps aux | grep '[s]erver' | awk '{print $2}')"/>
            </sequential>
          </parallel>
        </target>
```

The build fails where I've written the comment.

It's indeed pretty logical since once my test are done, I simply ssh on the same server & kill the process of the first parallel task.

But in my run-test-shutdown process it's a completely normal behaviour, so I was wondering if it was possible to sort of catch this BUILD FAIL error so my ant project could continue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ant [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task has an attribute `failonerror` which defaults to true - perhaps you can set this to false for your shutdown target.